# propriedade name textarea name="q1" ate name="q20" + php

Tags: php

Preciso que a propriedade `name="q1"` gere uma sequência, tipo assim:

```
<textarea name="q1"></textarea>
<textarea name="q2"></textarea>
<textarea name="q3"></textarea> 
.
.
. <!-- // Até -->
<textarea name="q20"></textarea>
```

Meu código abaixo:

```
forEach($resultado as $y){ ?>
    <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q1"><?php echo $y['ipco_descr_item']; ?></label> 

    <textarea rows="3" cols="30" class="fs-anim-lower" id="q1" **name="q1"** placeholder="Resposta"> </textarea>
    <div id="resposta"></div>

    <?php 
    }
```

Comment: Quer gerar várias `<textarea>` cada uma com seu `qx`? Esse numero vem de onde? do `$resultado`que está a ser iterado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se quer repetir essa linha pode criar um loop aí e concatenar o numero que está a ser iterado.

```
forEach($resultado as $y){ ?>
    <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q1"><?php echo $y['ipco_descr_item']; ?></label> 
    <?php 
    for($i = 1; $ < 21; $i++){
        echo '<textarea rows="3" cols="30" class="fs-anim-lower" id="q1" name="q'.$i.'" placeholder="Resposta"> </textarea>';
    }
    ?>
    <div id="resposta"></div>

    <?php 
    }
```

O ciclo `for` vai de 1 a 20 e na propriedade que quer juntar o numero pode fazer `name="q'.$i.'"` para juntar o numero à letra.

Answer (score 4):

É melhor você fazer assim:

```
foreach($resultado as $y){ ?>
   <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q[]"><?php echo $y['ipco_descr_item']; ?></label> 
   <textarea rows="3" cols="30" class="fs-anim-lower" id="q[]" name="q[]" placeholder="Resposta"> </textarea>
  <div id="resposta"></div>
<?php 
}
```

E receba os dados assim:

```
if (isset($_POST['q'])){
  foreach ($_POST['q'] as $key => $value) {
     echo 'field: q'.$key.'<br>';
     echo 'value: '.$value.'<br><hr><br>';
  }
}
```

Mas se achar difícil fazer dessa forma, você pode gerar o seu código assim:

```
$i = 1;
foreach($resultado as $y){ ?>
   <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q<?=$i?>"><?php echo $y['ipco_descr_item']; ?></label> 
   <textarea rows="3" cols="30" class="fs-anim-lower" id="q<?=$i?>" name="q<?=$i?>" placeholder="Resposta"> </textarea>
  <div id="resposta"></div>
<?php 
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Kadu, deu certo.